# How do I add an index signature for a mapped type?

Tags: typescript, mapped-types, index-signature

Suppose I have interface

```
interface X {
   a: string;
   b: number;
   c: boolean;
}
```

and a function

```
function values(x: X) {
   return Object.keys(x).map(s => x[s])
}
```

When I enable typescript's `strict` flag I get the error "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'X' has no index signature". So to make it explicit, I can just add an index signature to the definition of X

```
[key: string]: any;
```

Easy peasy.

---

However if I X is now a mapped type instead:

```
type X<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: string;
}
```

and I have the function

```
function values<T>(x: X<T>) {
  return Object.keys(x).map(s => x[s])
}
```

where am I supposed to add the index signature? Is there any way to make this explicit without resorting to doing something gross like `Object.keys(x).map(s => (x as any)[s])`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can:

```
interface X {
    a: string;
    b: number;
    c: boolean;
    [key: string]: X[keyof X];
}
```

The result of `X[keyof X]` will now be `(string | number | boolean)`, which works even better than `any` because the return of your function will be `(string | number | boolean)[]`.

[Example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20X%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20c%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20X%5Bkeyof%20X%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20values(x%3A%20X)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20Object.keys(x).map(s%20%3D%3E%20x%5Bs%5D)%3B%0D%0A%7D)

Another way that should work with both examples is:

```
function values(x: X) {
    const keys = Object.keys(x) as (keyof X)[];
    return keys.map(s => x[s]);
}
```

Not pretty, but at least more typed than `(x as any)`.

Of course it can be made generic too:

```
function values<T>(x: T) {
    const keys = Object.keys(x) as (keyof T)[];
    return keys.map(s => x[s]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Meligy. Yeah you're right I could have made the index signature more specific in my first example, but that wasn't really what I was interested in. My question is more around how to add the index signature to the second example

Comment: If you don't want too much ceremony (and maybe casting to `any` as a middle casting, then casting to something else to not loose typing completely), then there's not much to do. I assume the 2nd example was to solve the problem of the first, right? I added another way to do it, let me know your thoughts.

Comment: If your target is to make the first example generic, I added a 3rd example for that too.

Comment: Nice one! I figured that was probably the best way to do it.

I find it a little disappointing that `Object.keys(x)` has type `string[]` instead of `(keyof T)[]` although the core contributors' objections to doing it that way do make sense too

Comment: sweet jesus, thank you @Meligy . I've been trying to solve this for _days_! in case someone is trying to do this with a string enum: `enum eFoo { a = 'a', b = 'b' }; interface Foo { [key: string]: eFoo[keyof eFoo]; }` https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=enum%20eX%20%7Bdex%20%3D%20'dex'%2C%20str%20%3D%20'str'%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20X%20%7B%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20eX%5Bkeyof%20eX%5D%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20xs%3A%20X%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afor%20(let%20k%20in%20eX)%20xs%5Bk%5D%20%3D%2010%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(xs%2Cxs.dex)%3B