# How to use for...in with key in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I am facing a problem when migrating my JSX code to TSX as follows:

[image: TS error message]

This is the interface:

```
interface IParams {
  user_id: string;
  first: number;
  started_at: Date;
  ended_at: Date;
}
```

This code works as entended in JSX and Google does not seem to have a definite answer for this, how could I fix this somehow ?

Thank you!

NVH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make it work by defining the type of key to be explicit i.e.

```js
let key: keyof IParams;
for (key in params) {
  url.searchParams.set(key, params[key]);
}
```

Alternatively if all you are trying to do is get the value you could do so by using `Object.entries` which would look like:

```js
for (const [key, value] in Object.entries(params)) {
  url.searchParams.set(key, value);
}

// or if you wanted to use forEach

Object.entries(params).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  url.searchParams.set(key, value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To allow type safe indexing you can add an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) with the `string` key type to the type. A similar question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47464764/how-do-i-add-an-index-signature-for-a-mapped-type), and for `IParams`, it would look something like:

```typescript
interface IParams {
  user_id: string;
  first: number;
  started_at: Date;
  ended_at: Date;
  [key: string]: string | number | Date;
};
```

or using [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html)s in concert with [`keyof`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html) (as in the linked question):

```typescript
interface IParams {
  user_id: string;
  first: number;
  started_at: Date;
  ended_at: Date;
  [key: string]: IParams[keyof IParams];
};
```

which would cover the situation where more fields are added to the type.

Altogether, the following compiles and runs fine for me:

```typescript
interface IParams {
  user_id: string;
  first: number;
  started_at: Date;
  ended_at: Date;
  [key: string]: IParams[keyof IParams];
};

const params: IParams = {
  user_id: 'user_id',
  first: 0,
  started_at: new Date(),
  ended_at: new Date()
};

for (const key in params) {
  console.log(`${key} = ${params[key]}`);
}
```

with the following output:

```
user_id = user_id
first = 0
started_at = Tue Aug 31 2021 16:08:24 GMT+1000 (Australian Eastern Standard Time)
ended_at = Tue Aug 31 2021 16:08:24 GMT+1000 (Australian Eastern Standard Time)
```